# Thick film resistors failure mode

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, failure

I'm experiencing failures on thick film resistors.

In a metering device which samples the mains voltage through a voltage divider formed by a series of 150K 1% 1206 SMD resistors, many of the resistors have increased in resistance value to 10M or more.

- Has anybody experienced this failure mode?
- What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Can you share a schematic showing exactly how things are connected? (for example, exactly how many 150k resistors do you have in series). What is mains voltage in your country? And exactly which 150k resistors are you using (a datasheet link would be ideal)?

Comment: I have seen it in leaded (metal film and otherwise) resistors exposed to high DC voltage. Possibly silver migration. Seems like common with AC voltage applied.

Comment: What is the  voltage rating for the resistor in its datasheet?

Comment: Schematic? Is there AC or DC voltage across the resistor?

Answer (score 1):

We can only assume you used safe margins of 50% for power dissipation and working voltage.

With 240Vac and 1206 components that means using 100Vac per part instead of 200Vw and using 0.125W max instead of 0.25W.

I would hope you have at least a string of 4 Resistors with Transorb or MOV protection.

Being large parts they must be placed in parallel to board edge breaks for depanelization de-stress.

Comment: We are using the YAGEO RC series resistance 1% tolerance. The service voltage is 220Vac and we have 6 resistors (150K each) connected in series.

Comment: @pablo1323 Knowing you have six resistors in series is important. Edit this into your original post.

Comment: have you checked for mechanical failure yet?  (micro-cracks under 10x magnifier.)  What environment is it failing under?  Production , home use? lab?

Comment: My guess overheated by hand-soldering and mechanical failure.